# How many equivalence classes does this set have?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let be  $ \underline{7}$ ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} $ $How many elements does the equivalence $\rho \subseteq \underline{7} \times \underline{7} $ have if

(1) it consists of 2 equivalence classes, and these classes hold 3 and 4 elements

(2) it consists of 4 equivalence classes, and these classes hold 1,2,2,2 elements

The equivalence classes have the following 3 properties:

They aren't empty,every two equivalence classes,are either equal or disjoint. Would it help to me if I would represent the classes with directed graphs?

Comment: 7 has the Bell number of 203, so I think that both solutions will be less than 203

Comment: This is just simple combinatorics. How many elements do you need in $\rho$ for an equivalence class of 1 element? 2 elements? 3 elements? 4 elements?

Comment: The question in the title (How many equivalence classes are there?) and the question in the body (how many elements does the *equivalence* have?) are two different questions. I'm assuming you mean the latter, as the problem statement gives the number of equivalence classes; is that correct?

Comment: yeah, you think it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer doesn't depend on how the particular elements are called/denoted, without loss of generality we can assume that the equivalence classes are $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{4,5,6,7\}$ for (1) and $\{1\},\ \{2,3\},\ \{4,5\}, \{6,7\}$ for (2).

1. The elements of $\rho$ are the $7$ reflection pair $(x,x)$ plus
   $(1,2),\ (1,3),\ (2,3)$ and their reversed pairs, and all possible pairs of $\{4,5,6,7\}$ in both permutations. Altogether $7+2\cdot \binom 32+2\cdot\binom 42$.
2. It's similar and even easier.

Comment: I get $105$ for (2) is that true?

Comment: Noo.. It is $7+2+2+2\ =\ 13$

Comment: I calculated 7+2+2+2+2=15, but wrote 105...

Comment: Ah ok.. that 105 seems just so far from the exercise:)